# Is is possible to catch if the creation of a web worker if failing?

Tags: html, error-handling, web-worker

In the example below there is in an error in the code for the web worker (undefined reference) but **try { ... } catch(e) { ...}** does not catch much. The message *Why am I here ?* appears on the console.

HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var worker;
try {
  worker = new Worker("foo.js");
  console.log('Why am I here ?');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error creating the worker.');
}
// No matter what, an object "worker" will created during the call to Worker()
// How to test that all went well
var worker_failed = false;
worker.addEventListener("error",
                        function(e) { worker_failed = true },
                        false);
// Is it correct to assume that "worker" is created asynchronously, and that checking
// that creation went well should not be sequential and the test below is not
// the way to do it ?
if ( worker_failed ) {
  // Worker("foo.js") failed, switch to plan B
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Web worker (*foo.js*):

```
foobar = 2 + baz; // fails here (baz is undefined)
onmessage = function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  postMessage(data);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle errors in your workers asynchronously. You need to listen to the `error` event of the worker.

> worker.addEventListener("error", onError, false);

There's a great tutorial about web workers [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). You can find exactly what you're looking for in the `handling errors` section.

You can also check the official [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#runtime-script-errors) for more information about how this should be implemented by the browsers.

Comment: But then the error is caught after the worker is created, somehow. The sequence being: var worked = Worker('foo.js'); worker.addEventListener("error", onError, false);

Comment: Although after trying out a listener onError does receive the error fired... and the console also receives the error.

Comment: If you don't want the error to get to the console, you should catch it in the worker itself. As stated in the spec, _Whenever an uncaught runtime script error occurs in one of the worker's scripts,[...] the user agent must report the error at the URL of the resource that contained the script_. The chrome debugger is probably listening to the `error` event the same way you are and passing that info to the console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments; I edited the question. It helps reasoning about the issue, and this is pointing toward the guess that the constructor Worker() is asynchronous (and code conditional to a smooth initialization be in a callback). What brought me here is the currently very uneven state of browsers regarding web workers (for what matters Firefox 15.0 has the most working for me, although it remains very easy to crash).

Comment: I think you have a concept error here. There is no error in the creation of your worker. Any errors in the creation would be caught by your `try{} catch{}` clause. What you have is a runtime error. JS is an interpreted language, so errors like the one you have aren't caught until execution. Hence, the error is thrown when the worker gets executed (in another thread). Finally, as the specs say, any uncaught errors there would be passed on the the parent url using the `onError` API.

Comment: I am seeing now that I thought of the evaluation of "foo.js" in the call `Worker("foo.js")` as the creation of the worker and as the top-level components in that file as methods and attributes for the worker. That's not the case. The fact that they are local to be worker must have got wired to other concepts in my head. The origin of the  question was that I cannot guess whether a browsers implements what I need from web workers before I try out creating one with its associated Javascript code. Something like testing `if (window.Worker) { worker = new Worker("foo.js") } else { < plan B > }`.